# Empty Tracelogs in Springboot console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, logback

I am trying to implement trace context for my Spring Boot application.

I have added the following dependency,

> implementation
> 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-logback-1.0:0.16.1'

My logback-spring.xml file is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"><encoder>
        <pattern><![CDATA[%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{15}#%line %X{req.requestURI} traceId: %X{trace_id} spanId: %X{span_id} %msg\n]]></pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="OTEL" class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But I am seeing only clumsy and empty traces like below

```
17:03:57.851 [main] INFO  o.s.c.c.s.GenericScope#283  traceId:  spanId:  BeanFactory id=b301daf5-b80a-67e2-bcc9-d6e276481af3
```

Followed by the error

```
ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication#824  traceId:  spanId:  Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otelRestTemplateBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/spring/autoconfigure/httpclients/resttemplate/RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'otelRestTemplateBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0;
```

Any hints on the same will be quite helpful.

Comment: in root tag can you additionally adding one more appender ref for OTEL?